# How is "special rates" used in the St. Trinian's school song?

Tags: british-english, slang, lyrics

The following lyrics from "Defenders of Anarchy" on the [St. Trinian's (2007)](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0964587/) soundtrack have actually confused me for some time because I can't tell whether "special rates" is being used in a British slang sense I'm unaware of.

> So scam all the toffs the neats and the freaks,
> Blackmail the goths, the slappers and the geeks,
> And if they complain we'll do it all again.
> We do as we damn well please
>
> The ASBOs, the chavs, the emos and their mates,
> To torment the slags we offer special rates,
> And if they complain we'll do it all again.
> Defenders of anarchy

As an American I usually think of "special rates" meaning a discount, but I could also see it meaning an extra markup for the kind of customer for whom a "special" effort is required just because they're so annoying.

So, is there a slang connotation here, a misuse, a regular use, or have I just been overthinking it?

Comment: Is there a part of that song that's *not* sarcastic?

Comment: I don't believe so, no. But I'm wondering if there's something else here one needs to be deeply versed in British slang to grok. Asbos and chavs are easy to google, but this phrase not so much. :)

Comment: St Trinians dates from 1946 - running until 1952 as a comic strip series - subsequently made into films. *Asbos* and *chavs* are from a much later date - presumably a reincarnation of St Trinians which had passed me by.

Comment: Revised based on Robusto's and WS2's followups.

Comment: It looks like it means they are offering a "deal" for tormenting the slags, presumably because they enjoy that sort of entertainment and (following the logic of the song) don't want to price themselves out of such an activity.

Comment: In addition to Robusto's comment it could allude to sexual acts for money, as a *slag* is someone (overly) sexually promiscuous, perhaps they're suggesting they are under-cutting the *slags* in a price-war.

Answer (score -1):

Being offered *special rates* in this context means violence, not a monetary amount.

The subjects in each verse are despised and are being treated as such.

The threat of violence is given euphemistically, and sometimes is stated as *don't worry, we'll look after you, you will also get special rates!*

Comment: More of an explanation is needed to make it intelligible how the phrase came to have that meaning.

Comment: how it came to have that meaning wasn't in the original question